# intent.getStringExtra() returns null but String != null is true? Android

Tags: android

I am just wondering what the hell is going on under the hood when the intent extra doesn't exist in the first place?

For example:

```
String remindOnString = intent.getStringExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDON);

if(remindOnString != null && !remindOnString.equals(""))
    mRemindDateTime = Timestamp.valueOf(remindOnString);
```

It is quite strange to me the expression: `remindOnString != null` is true despite the fact that remindOnString receives null.

Here is the screenshot of the watches I set for this variable:

[image]

I don't know if I missed something from the documentation. But this is very strange to me. According to the tool-tip (Which I believe from the api-docs)
`intent.getStringExtra(KEY)` returns the string or null.

What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Maybe the `remindOnString` hold the string **"null"**. You should try to print the remindOnString value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns value "null" but still a object .

Comment: I don't understand, checking a string for nullness is simply as str != null. How can a string object hold a null value but still an object? Of course str is an object per declaration but doesn't refer to anything. That is why I am checking if String is refering to a null. I can confirm iRavi iVooda though, the count on the string value is 4.

Comment: i am also saying it it having the value "null" as iravi ivooda

Comment: Alright, thanks for clearing that to me. Now this leads me to my next question. Why is it returning "null"?

Comment: I can confirm this now, it does return "null". I think I will have to post question about this on the forums for further clarification. Thank you!

Comment: ask that i maybe able to answer that too @NeonWarge

Comment: It returns "null" because somewhere that value was set.  Show the code which creates the intent.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : The OP already knows the 'extra' doesn't exist - the issue was about why `remindOnString` has a value of null but a test for `remindOnString != null` is showing to be true, i.e., it has a null value but testing to see if the String instance is null shows it isn't. You need to drill down the source for Intent -> Bundle -> BaseBundle to see what's going on. The `BaseBundle` method `getString(...)` returns an `Object` cast to a `String` - the `Object` is returned from the `BaseBundle` mMap which is an `ArrayMap<String, Object>` using `mMap.get(...)` ...continued in next comment

Comment: @ChrisStratton : ...what the `ArrayMap` method for `get(String name)` returns if the key isn't found isn't clear to me (I haven't looked at the source for `ArrayMap` yet) and also how a Java `String` behaves when an instance is created implicitly by a cast from a (possibly null) `Object` isn't clear to me. I suspect it may be the Java `String` creation which is applying a default "null" text as a result of the `Object` being null.

Comment: @Squonk - it has a value of "null" which is of course not the same as *being* null.  The documentation is quite explicit that ArrayMap.get() "Returns the value associated with the given key, or null if there is no such key." That would be `null` **not "null"**.