# Intent.getStringExtra() returns literal "null"

Tags: java, android

On this post I made [intent.getStringExtra() returns null but String != null is true? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975924/intent-getstringextra-returns-null-but-string-null-is-true-android)

I wanted to ask if this is possible at all that a nonexistent key on intent extras could return a literal null? On my case, `intent.getStringExtra(NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDON)` returns literal null.

I definitely have done something wrong. On my case, the NoteExtrasKey.EXTRA_NOTE_REMINDON can become null whenever a user decides not to put on date reminders. So, there could be no instance of that key on the intent extra. Could that be the reason why it is returning literal null?

I have min version set to 8 and targeting 22. Any input will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your key becomes null?

Comment: This is not meaningfully different from your existing question.  Don't repost - if you are not satisfied there, work with those who have responded to it to develop your original question until you understand the issue.